# Using \DeclareKeys as a document author/designer

Tags: key-value, l3keys

Say I want to use a package using [`l3keys`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf) for it options, e.g. I want to print numbers using [`siunitx`](https://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx)'s `\num`. I load it with my desired default options (e.g. just `\usepackage{siunitx}`) but have a recurring use-case in which I want to pass a number of different settings to `\num`. I don't want to type all the options each time but rather have a custom, short key that does it for me (e.g. `\num[foo]{<number>}`. Am I supposed to just use `\DeclareKeys` in the preamble? E.g.

```latex
\DeclareKeys[siunitx]{
  foo .meta:n = {
      round-mode      = figures     ,
      round-precision = 3           ,
      exponent-mode   = scientific  ,
    },
}
```

This macro is documented in [`clsguide.pdf`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/clsguide.pdf) and not mentioned in [`usrguide.pdf`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/usrguide.pdf) which makes me unsure if it is intended for such a use-case. It also feels a bit weird to add keys to the `siunitx` "namespace", but I guess that's unavoidable with the intended usage.

Answer (score 4):

Adding a key to the package namespace is exactly the same conceptually as what you'd do in `pgf` if you declare a `.style` key, it's just that you probably don't notice it. (I agree that this is likely something that should be documented with guidance on what is good practice.)

Taking the specific, if you want to add directly to `siunitx` then yes you can use `\DeclareKeys`, although I think it's probably better to see this as a 'programmer' use of the API and to use `\keys_define:nn` in an `\ExplSyntaxOn` context. (All of the `siunitx` programmers API is formally documented, so you can rely on the names of keys being in this namespace - it's explicitly mentioned in the manual.)

Comment: I've asked the team for general views here

Comment: the main problem is, that siunitx perhaps in the feature will define a key `foo` to, so I would suggest to use some naming scheme, that makes a clash improbable.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes: I wonder if we might describe a convention that leaves a 'namespace' for this, e.g. 'Name any meta-keys as `user-...`'?

Comment: For me the difference to `pgfkeys`' `.style` is that the "ownership" of namespaces (by package authors etc.) is not really a thing there, while it is very much encouraged in LaTeX3. That's what made me unsure if this is the right approach here.

Comment: I agree that a convention for a user namespace is probably the way to go (there might be another way similar to `pgfkeys`' handling of uknown keys (not sure if that exists in `l3keys`), i.e. "native" keys shadowing user keys, but that's probably too obtuse to be the norm and would not really solve the problem in the end). However I fear that `user-foo` might be too long for it to catch on (people don't like long keys). Maybe a single character (e.g. `:foo` or `~foo`) is preferable?

Comment: @schtandard Using the `unknown` key mechanism is certainly possible, but I've not considered that

Comment: @JosephWright that would still only be a convention and every package would have to accommodate for that, imho, just a simple `my`-prefix is enough (instead of `user-`).